# Instance correct declaration

Tags: c++, oop, instance

```
class Node{
    public:
       int key;
       int height;
       Node *left;
       Node *right;
};
```

Why does creating an instance like Node x() not work and Node *x=new Node() works?

Comment: For which language is this question?

Comment: This question is for C++

Comment: Then please add the c++ tag to your question.

Comment: `Node x()` is the declaration of a function that returns a `Node`. Use `Node x` instead.